# Finding an expression for the generating function of a sequence using algebraic operations

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, generating-functions

All done using geometric series $\sum_{n>0} ^{\infty} x^n$

a) Find expression for the generating function of the sequence with terms $q_n=n^4$.

b) Find expression for the generating function of the sequence with terms
 $r_n=\sum_{k=0} ^n  k^4$.

For a) I basically started with:

$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$, etc.

and differentiated and multiplied by $x$ consecutively a few times to come up with the answers for a) and b) and b) was just $\frac{1}{1-x}$ times a).

But I can't help but feel my answers are wrong, so I was wondering if somebody could confirm if I was doing the right thing? I.e. multiplying  by $x$ both sides, differentiate with respect to $x$, etc. etc. consecutively a few times till pattern looks like generating function of $q_n$ and $r_n$?

also,  I was wondering for part c), find a polynomial expression for r_n, I have no idea how to do that, apparently by induction is incorrect, and have to use convolution or something

Comment: You seem to have the right idea.  But you might get better feedback if you told us your results.

Comment: noo its ok I figured out my result, but, I was wondering for part c), find a polynomial expression for r_n, I have no idea how to do that, apparently by induction is incorrect, and have to use convolution or something :/

Comment: Based on your last Comment you are actually "wondering for part c)", which does not appear in the body of the Question currently.  Please edit your Question while it has not received an Answer, to avoid Readers wasting time.